# Permalink problem ( Blog posts vs custom post types)

Tags: permalinks

I have add `/blog/%postname%` permalink option for blog posts.

Sample blog post : domain.com/blog/post-name/

I have custom post type called product. Now it permalink display as follow.

domain.com/blog/product/product-name/

I need to use it as domain.com/product/product-name/ . How to do it? (Blog posts should be domain.com/blog/post-name/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `with_front` to `false` when you register the post type to prevent any static prefix in your permalink structure from being prepended on custom post type permalinks.

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'       => 'product',
        'with_front' => false
    ),
    // other args...
);
```